# JavaDoc, Property description

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I have a private field of type `FloatProperty`. It can be accessed by "JavaFX" Getters/ Setters.

Eclipse shows me some JavaDoc, which seems to be autogenerated somehow from the field's JavaDoc.

Also, there is some "Property description" in the javaDoc Popup. Is this Eclipse specific or is this JavaDoc somehow generated on the fly, since the method itself does not have any JavaDoc.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**: Seems to be Eclipse specific, at least the "Property Description" part.. General description and some `@See` tags are autogenerated nevertheless.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you generate the javadoc and see by yourself?

Comment: Your javadoc comment is at the field. The screenshot shows the property method and the property getter though. Why would you expect the field's documentation to be automatically linked to the getter/setter. Also did you use the [`-javafx` option for `javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDCAFDD)???

Comment: I would not expect this. I am surprised that the JavaDoc from the field is taken over for the getter. I did not use the -javafx option, what does it do?